# Пуговица — разбор по составу

Tags: морфемный-разбор

В слове "пуговица" обычно выделяют суффикс ИЦ, например: [Разбор по составу слова «пуговица»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Но на каком основании?

ПУГОВИЦА, -ы; ж. Застёжка, продеваемая в петли одежды.  <Пуговичный, -ая, -ое. П-ое производство. П-ая фабрика. П-ая машина. Пуговичка, -и; ж. Уменьш.-ласк.

ПУГОВКА, ж. 1. Уменьш. к Пуговица.

Это слово выглядит как основное, **непроизводное**. Так, слово "пуговка" образуется **усечением** "пуговицы" на суффикс ИЦ.

Comment: А где же ответы?  Я думала, что все знают.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-иц

Answer (score 1):

Мне вот это нравится:

"Напротив, Перссон (245, 263) отделяет др.-инд. слова и относит *pǫgy к *pǫkъ (см. пук, польск. рąk «почка», рęk «пучок»), предполагая различные расширения корня..."

Пучок, выпуклость, пук - собранное вместе.

То есть пуг+ов+ица, как по+сл+ов+ица( от сл+ух(ухо), сл+ыть, корень сл.), как луковица, половица.

-иц какой-то новый суффикс, который хоть и обозначает предмет, явление(? метелица что ли?), а точнее объект. Только логика не от прилагательного явно, половица не от половой, а от пол. Ов - относящийся к, к полу. Полов+иц, иц частица, что-то отдельное, относящаяся к + часть. Пуговица - что-то отдельное относящееся к собиранию вместе.

Например, в той же вики "образовано от мужского рода" - бред. Полковница - это жена полковника, а не полковник в юбке. Особняком тут будет разве что императрица. Она не мастер, а в смысле делать мастер - мастерица делать что-то. Можно сказать "я - мастер", но нельзя сказать "я - мастерица", или "спасибо, мастерица" - тоже криво, "спасибо, ты - мастерица делать, ты просто мастерица." Мастерица - существительное близкое к прилагательному, какая мастерица, а не кто мастерица. Какая ты красавица - какая ты красивая, какая ты умница - какая ты умная. какой ты умник - вообще негативный смысл выходит, а есть еще какой ты умница))).

А если кобылица - это от кобыл, что ли?))) А нет, тут они вдруг пишут, что мол это уменьшительно-ласкательный - с чего вдруг? Кобылица - это обладающая кобыльностью, свойством кобылы. -ица - это что-то обладающее или наделенное свойством, качеством. Лужица - это не маленькая лужа, это что-то мокрое, влажное, лужица. Сестра - родственница, сестрица - обращение к качеству, братец - тоже. Братец не тот, кто брат - родственник, а тот, к кому братское отношение.

Луковица - это то, что относится к луку, а лук - это вершки, стрелки, луковица же внизу, её не видно, корень.

Пуговица - это то, с помощью чего собирают платье вместе. Частицы для "сбора платья", не сам пук, а для сбора в пучок.

Answer (score 0):

Из содержимого [этимологического словаря](https://etymological.academic.ru/4154/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), можно сделать вывод, что оба слова имеют одного "предка" - слова **"пугъвъ"**.

> Искон. Др.-рус. суф. образование от пугъвъ «пуговица» (< пугы) (ср. морковь < моркы и т. д.). Того же корня, что пуга «подушечка», др.-инд. pūgas «куча», латышск. paũgurs «холм» и т. д. Пуговица названа по своей первоначальной «вздутости», утолщеннрсти.

Таким образом они оба образованы суффиксальным способом

Comment: Вывод некорректный. При морфемном и словообразовательном разборах нас интересует  современное состояние языка и современные схемы словообразования, действующие в настоящий момент. В этимологии рассматривается историческая грамматика.  Этимология слова определяет его происхождение и развитие на протяжении всей истории.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что этимология не играет никакой роли в словообразовании?

Comment: Да, именно это.  Значение слова и его состав менялись со временем,  (Особенно хорош  историко-этимологический словарь Черных.)   Мы же должны ориентироваться на самые современные словари.  К тому же и теория меняется. Я так толком и не разобралась в теме. Сравниваю словари  Тихонова 1978 года (со словообразовательными гнездами)  и современный словарь 2002 года, а они различаются. И теория у всех написана как-то путано, нет ясности (формальный принцип, семантический принцип и т.д.)